# I want to store a php $_SESSION variable and retrieve it on another page

Tags: php

```
<?php 
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['count']=0; ?>

<html><head></head>
<body>
<?php include ("getElement.php");
echo getLinkButton("myscript.php", "myscript.php"); 
echo $_SESSION['count']++; ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

The code above works, but when I click the link to navigate to myscript.php:

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

I get this error:
Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/ubuntu/public_html/myscript.php  on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myscript.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

You must include session_start at the top of all pages you wish to use the session in.

Answer (score 4):

Use `session_start()` in the second page too, before accessing the `$_SESSION` superglobal array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do `session_start();` on every page you want to use the session-vars and also be sure you have cookies enabled or send the session-id with every link and form.